# Selecting cells within polygon layer without extracting them using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, select-by-location

I know how to use the tool, `Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > Extract by mask` for cells that lie within a polygon shapefile, but is there anyway to just select those cells without having to extract them?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is your purpose of doing this and why is a new raster extracted not desired?

Answer (score 0):

In the Online Help there is a [Raster selection options](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-selection-options.htm) page:

> The selection environment allows you to perform queries based on data
>   within the raster catalog or mosaic dataset and its relationship to
>   feature layers. For example, using Select By Location or Select By
>   Attribute from the Selection menu, you could select the following:
>
> - A set of raster datasets by cloud cover criteria
> - Raster datasets by date
> - Raster datasets based on location for features in a feature layer or graphic

It seems to me that these selections are being applied to the index layer rather than to individual cells.

There is another page [About cell selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/about-cell-selection.htm) which relates to ArcScan and says:

> The ability to select raster cells can help make the vectorization
>   process more efficient. Raster cell selection is often used during the
>   raster cleanup process. Additionally, during automatic vectorization
>   you may choose to only vectorize selected cells. ArcScan allows for
>   two types of cell selection methods: interactive and expression-based
>   selections. Cell selections support other processes, such as raster
>   cleanup and generating features. This section provides an overview of
>   cell selections.

I am not clear what requirement you are trying to meet but, in any event, I think you should be or become aware of these pages in order to know what is already available.