# Summing pixel values within polygon zone in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, extract-by-mask

My question is the same as [Summing pixel values within polygon zone in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43425/19874) but I'm working with ArcGIS and not QGIS.

I have a raster data set with values of type float.

[image]

And a polygon shapefile

[image]

I want to calculate mean of all raster cell values that are completely within the shapefile

In order to do so, I have used `Extract by mask` tool and now I have the following raster with `NULL` values for cells that are outside the polygon layer.

[image]

But there are 3 problems:

1. All parts of each masked pixel is not within the shapefile.

[image]

I want to mask just the pixels that are completely within polygon shapefile.

2. I don't know how to sum up all cell values in a masked raster?
3. I don't know how to count the number of such cells and calculate the mean?

Comment: @fatih_dur I've explained about my purpose [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227130/how-to-select-cells-within-a-polygon-layer-without-extracting-them?noredirect=1#comment351266_227130)

Comment: To give your questions a more professional feel I recommend that you always write "want to" instead of "wanna".